# WCF with MSMQ Testing

Tags: c#, netmsmqbinding

I have a [ServiceContract] MyServiceContract with some methods decorated with  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)].  One of the methods is called LoadFile.

I have a ChannelFactory with NetMsmqBinding (ExactlyOnce = true) and EndPointAddress("net.msmq://localhost/private/MyService.svc").

I have an MSMQ set up as Transactional and named "MyService.svc".

In my application, there comes a time when I call ChannelFactory.CreateChannel to get a concrete instance of MyService (which implements MyServiceContract).

When I call LoadFile on that instance, it sends a message to my MSMQ.

When I am running in a release environment, that LoadFile method that went to my MSMQ gets pulled off and executed.

When I am running in a local machine test environment, that LoadFile method that went to my MSMQ just sits there.

I suspect that MyService is not running.  But if that is the case, I don't know how to start it.

Comment: two things:  using msmq locally can sometimes require different names like . (single dot)  or your local machine name  .    If your service can do something like write a text file that says "hello" getdate and call that before msmq work you could verify it is running.

Comment: Thanks.  Items are showing up in my MSMQ, so I'm pretty sure the name is fine.